# Не могу решить задачу по Python. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно начал учить python. написал вот такой код и не могу понять откуда берется пробел в ответе. Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
one = input().split(' ')
two = input().split(' ')
three = set(one) - set(two)
print(*three)
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать пробел из сплита, он по умолчанию бьет по ним, причем немного иным способом

Comment: Print напечатал. Из примера  one = [1, 2, 3]  two = [2]  three = set(one) - set(two) = [1, 3] print(*three)
выводить в консоль  "1 пробел 3"

Comment: Как вы обработаете пару последовательностей `1 1` и `2`?

Comment: Про сортировку забыли.

Comment: Человек спросил "откуда берется пробел в ответе"

Answer (score 2):

Если ввод для `input`'ов не включает больше одного пробельного символа между объектами и строка не начинается и не оканчивается на пробел, то код вполне рабочий.

Если же ввод будет таким

```py
 10 5   7 9
```

То операция `split(' ')`, будет иметь следующий вид

```py
['', '10', '5', '', '', '7', '9', '']
```

Поскольку вы используете `set`-тип данных, то на выходе вы будете иметь следующее множество

```py
{'', '10', '5', '7', '9'}
```

Что можно сделать? В лоб, удалить из множества пустой член

```py
s = set(one) # {'', '10', '5', '7', '9'}
s.remove('') if '' in s else s # {'10', '5', '7', '9'}
```

Или весь код можно записать так, не указывая разделитель вовсе:

```py
one = set(input().split())
two = set(input().split())

three = one - two
print(*three)
```

**UPD**

Увидел после комментарий про сортировку. Да, у множеств есть метод `sorted` и я немного переработал функцию к такому виду для того, чтобы `set`ы содержали данные в числовом формате, который можно отсортировать.

```py
def to_set_without_spaces(str_=None) -> set:
    if str_ == None:
        str_ = input()
    str_ = str_.split()
    set_ = {int(i) for i in str_}
    return set_
```

И вызов `print(*sorted(three))` будет давать нужный результат

Тест

```py
test_data = [('  1   2 3 ',' 2 '), 
             ('10   5 7 9 ',' 5 6 '), 
             ('1 2 3 ', ' 1 2 3  ')]

for i in test_data:
    three = to_set_without_spaces(i[0]) - to_set_without_spaces(i[1])
    print(*sorted(three))

# OUT
# 1 3
# 7 9 10
#
```

Функция избыточна и написана для того, чтобы можно было бы прогнать через тест логику, которая реализована. Без функции

```py
one = {int(i) for i in input().split()} # Просим ввести данные, разделяем их  в список, приводим к числовому формату для возможности сортировки
two = {int(i) for i in input().split()} # повторяем то же самое для второго набора данных

three = one - two
print(*sorted(three))
```

Comment: Проще вызвать `input().split()`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, спать пора

Comment: А есть какое-то более просто решение с командами, которые применял?(input, split, списки, множества)

Comment: @Sd1g что вы подразумеваете под "простое"? у вас используется `set`, а это множество, которое не упорядочено. Чтобы его отсортировать надо привести тип данных к `int` для каждого члена множества. Второе, есть такое утверждение "если ты пишешь обработку два раза, значит в этом месте должна быть функция". Это принцип DRY -> don't repeat yourself

Comment: Я понимаю, что нет смысла повторять то же самое по несколько раз. Просто нам функции еще не давали и скорее всего их не будет у нас (у меня на программе преподают основы питона). Есть какое-то решение просто в лоб, без функций?

Comment: @Sd1g давайте так. Первое, обучение - это сложный процесс. У вас есть уже все входные данные для того чтобы реализовать то, что вам необходимо. Второе, если у вас возникает новый вопрос, то сформулируйте и создайте новый вопрос. "Простое решение" - это очень субъективно и неопределено. Вытащить обработку из функции и применить два раза, это вам под силу. Я верю в вас